# XAMPP Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed phpmyadmin xampp

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a windows and I installed XAMPP for it, for a web app I am building as part of my class project. I installed it using recommended settings and didn't change anything, but when I try to access localhost/phpmyadmin, and even 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin, I get the error:

```
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

I looked at the other questions posted here on Stackoverflow about the same issue and tried some of the answers posted, but nothing seems to work. I am thoroughly confused and lost. Should I just find another service to use?

Comment: Do you see mysql running in XAMPP control panel ??

Comment: Yes. I just started it up, and it is running.

Comment: It works! I started Apache and MySQL, and now I can get in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned error caused due to mis-configuration of your PHPMyadmin's configuration settings.
 Check the user credentials mentioned in your PHPMyadmin's `config.inc.php` file.
As you said you are using xampp on windows the path will be similar like below:

```
C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php
```

In the above file check the below 2 lines (at around line #30):

```
/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
```

Comment: this solution is not working for me! what can be the solution